# How to update a particular column values in laravel-8?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-8

I am developing one api which is responsible for sending notification to mail this is working , now i want to update my Books table cart field all values should be zero(0) after successfully sending mail ,How to update a cart field values  in my books table all fileds set to be 0 when the notification successfully send to my mail ,How to acheive this thing please help me to fix this issue..

[image: this is my database]

`Books Migration table`

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateBooksTable extends Migration
{
  
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('books', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('author');
            $table->integer('price');
            $table->integer('quantity');
            $table->string('file')->nullable();
            $table->longText('description');
            $table->enum('cart', [0, 1])->default(0);
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

}
```

`CustomersController.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Customers;
use App\Models\Orders;
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Http\Resources\Books;
use App\Models\Books as ModelsBooks;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Notifications\orderSuccessfullNotification;
use PhpParser\Node\Expr\AssignOp\Mod;

class CustomersController extends Controller
{
  public function orderSuccessfull(Request $request){
      $cust=new Customers();
      $cust->user_id = auth()->id();
      $cust_id=Customers::where('user_id',$cust->user_id)->value('user_id');
     
      $user_email=User::where('id',$cust_id)->value('email');      
      $order = User::where('email', $user_email)->first();
      
      $ord = Orders::create(        
        [
            'orderNumber' => $order->orderNumber=rand(11111111,99999999),
            'customer_id'=>$order->id,
            'order_date'=>$order->order_date=Carbon::now(),      
        ]
    );

    $bookgetter1 = DB::table("Books")->select('name')->where('cart',['1'])->get();
    $bookgetter2 = DB::table("Books")->select('price')->where('cart',['1'])->get();
  
 
    if($order && $ord){
    $order->notify(new orderSuccessfullNotification($ord->orderNumber,$bookgetter1,$bookgetter2));
    //Here i want to update my books database cart field values should be 0
    //Books::where('cart')->values('0);
    }
      return response()->json(['message'=>'order created successfully','orderID'=>$ord->orderNumber]);
  }



  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you simply use  update query inside if condition

```
if($order && $ord){
    $order->notify(new orderSuccessfullNotification($ord->orderNumber,$bookgetter1,$bookgetter2));
  
    ModelsBooks::Where('cart','1')->update((['cart'=>'0']));
  }
```

Comment: may i know why you use `update((['cart'=>'0']))` instead of `update(['cart'=>0])` because I can't see it in the documentation. is it because it is `enum` field?  thank you

Comment: Actually the problem is in with missing ' ' this one for 1 value in where clause, it's an array value so we have to use '0' like this only .I hope this will clear my dear friend @JasonMigz

Answer (score 0):

You can do this through Eloquent:

```
ModelsBooks::where('cart','1')->update(['cart'=>'0']);
```

Or DB Query Builder:

```
DB::table('models_books')->where('cart', 1)->update(['cart' => '0']);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use Laravel Mass Updates:

```
ModelsBooks::where('id',1)->update(['cart'=>0]);
```

Make sure the `cart` field in `Books` Model is included in your `$fillable`

```
class Books extends Model
{
 /**
  * The attributes that are mass assignable.
  *
  * @var array
  */
  protected $fillable = ['cart'];
}
```

**Update:**

Credit to the Accepted Answer:

```
ModelsBooks::where('id',1)->update((['cart'=>0]));
```

Comment: "message": "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string",

Comment: Hai @Jason Migz, i am getting above error

Comment: @DevopsTraining apologize for the confusion it seem the error is from the `update(['cart'=>0])` which is wrong and the correct one is `update((['cart'=>'0']))` which i think because it is an `enum` data type.

Answer (score -1):

First solution
its simple just get the model whichever you want

```
$book = Book::where("condition")->first();
$book->fill(['book_price'=>25 // just example])
$book->update();
```

Second If you  want to create  then you could use updateorcreate method simply